# i got some problems with words reverse

Tags: c++

I am doing some algorithm programming, but i'm very confused with `getchar()` this method.
And here's the question required:

- input:Hello World Here I Come
- output:Come I Here World Hello

And I try to use `getchar()` to get every single char,and use a string variable to collect the char.
When the space comes, I use `stack` to push the current string variable into stack, making the string variable equals "". But whatever I try, the output always outputs gibberish, and I don't know how.

**Here's the code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

stack<string> re;// the stack

int main()
{

 char a;// the char to get very single char that print 
 string temp=""; 
 string all="";

while(a=getchar()!='\n')//if enter don't come
{
    if(a==(char)'32')//if the space come,push temp and reset the temp equals ""
    {
        re.push(temp);
        temp="";//so that i can collect a new word without last one
    }
    else
        temp+=a;//temp collects the char

}

while(!re.empty())//get every string from the stack
{
    if(re.size()==1)
    cout<<re.top();
    else
    cout<<re.top()<<" ";

    re.pop();   
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *`if(a==(char)'32')`* How does that compile? This is not a valid `char` literal.

Comment: so,should i use ' 'instead?but it doesn't work ,too.I tried to use a string variable to get all chars,but still gibberish.

Comment: Will probably not resolve your problem, but `(char)'32'`=> `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = getchar() != '\n'
```

`a` will be either 0 or 1, depending if character received is `'\n'` or not. It can be changed for example to:

```
a = getchar(), a != '\n'
```

another possibility could be:

```
(a = getchar()) != '\n'
```

You are also not pushing the last word to stack. String `all` was not used at all and hence I removed it.

Another issue, pointed in question comments, was invalid comparision if `a` is space: `(char)'32'` is not a space character, but `' '` is.

Corrected code (same identation as question):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

stack<string> re;// the stack

int main()
{
    char a;// the char to get very single char that print
    string temp = "";

    while ((a = getchar()) != '\n')//if enter don't come
    {
        if (a == ' ')//if the space come,push temp and reset the temp equals ""
        {
            re.push(temp);
            temp = "";//so that i can collect a new word without last one
        }
        else
            temp += a;//temp collects the char
    }
    if (!temp.empty())//if last word is not empty then push it to the stack
    {
        re.push(temp);
    }

    while (!re.empty())//get every string from the stack
    {
        if (re.size() == 1)
            cout << re.top();
        else
            cout << re.top() << " ";

        re.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```